# Deploy multiple containers in the storage account via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

Is it possible to deploy multiple (2) containers in the storage account via ARM Template?

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "",
      "apiVersion": "",      
      "location": "",
      "kind": "",
      "sku": {
        "name": ""
      },      
      "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[concat('default/', parameters('containerName'))]",
            "type": "blobServices/containers"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably want to trade that simplistic approach to something more manageable:

```
"variables": [
    "blobs": [
        "myfirstblob",
        "myotherblob"
    ]
],
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "",
      "apiVersion": "",      
      "location": "",
      "kind": "",
      "sku": {
        "name": ""
      },      
      "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[concat('default/', variables('blobs')[copyIndex()])]",
            "type": "blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "",
            "copy": {
                "name": "blobIterator",
                "count": "[length(variables('blobs'))]"
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

For example, you could use the template below to create a storage account with two containers named `container1` and `container2`.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccounts_joy12_name": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name')]",
            "location": "eastus",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_RAGRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "properties": {
                "networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "defaultAction": "Allow"
                },
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                "encryption": {
                    "services": {
                        "file": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                        },
                        "blob": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    },
                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                },
                "accessTier": "Hot"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'), '/default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'))]"
            ],
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_RAGRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "properties": {
                "cors": {
                    "corsRules": []
                },
                "deleteRetentionPolicy": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'), '/default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'))]"
            ],
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_RAGRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "properties": {
                "cors": {
                    "corsRules": []
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'), '/default/container1')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices', parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'), 'default')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "publicAccess": "None"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'), '/default/container2')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices', parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'), 'default')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_joy12_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "publicAccess": "None"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```